# iOS - Draw Bezier Path in Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

im learning CoreGraphic and want to make a simple game, but stuck on drawing thing with bezier path, i wanted to draw a triangle inside a subview, but it always come out wrong, i want it to fit 1/4 of the square view

My code:

```
UIBezierPath* trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[trianglePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.mainView.frame.size.width/2, self.mainView.frame.size.height/2)];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.mainView.frame.size.width, 0)];
[trianglePath closePath];

CAShapeLayer *triangleMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[triangleMaskLayer setPath:trianglePath.CGPath];

UIView *firstView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.mainView.frame.size.width, self.mainView.frame.size.height)];

firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:.75 alpha:1];
firstView.layer.mask = triangleMaskLayer;
[self.mainView addSubview:firstView];
```

It look like this:
[image]

Comment: If you don't draw the triangle, but just apply firstView, do you still have the frame issue? My guess, is that you draw when layout (linked to constraint) hasn't performed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dimensions are incorrect, you probably are creating the triangle before AutoLayout has done its job.

To ensure your `self.mainView` has the correct size, create your triangle in your controller `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

Also mind that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` may be called multiple times.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if (self.mainView.subviews.count == 0) {
        UIBezierPath* trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [trianglePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        [trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.mainView.frame.size.width/2, self.mainView.frame.size.height/2)];
        [trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.mainView.frame.size.width, 0)];
        [trianglePath closePath];

        CAShapeLayer *triangleMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        [triangleMaskLayer setPath:trianglePath.CGPath];

        UIView *firstView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.mainView.frame.size.width, self.mainView.frame.size.height)];

        firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:.75 alpha:1];
        firstView.layer.mask = triangleMaskLayer;
        [self.mainView addSubview:firstView];

    }
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```